# reseting the password using django authentication

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, passwords, reset-password

when I try to use Django's built-in password reset system. it does not take my templates into account. Moreover, when I click the reset password button then it takes me to the Django admin reset page([photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmfPt.jpg)).

My [the file map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEy0V.jpg)

my urls.py:-

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^login/$", auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name = "accounts/login.html"),name='login'),
    url(r"^logout/$", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='thanks.html'), name="logout"),
    url(r"^signup/$", views.SignUpView, name="signup"),
    url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',views.activate, name='activate'),
    url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html'), name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password_reset/done/$', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset/done/$', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
]
```

---

The Templates:-

password_reset_form.html

```
  {% extends 'reg_base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block body_block %}
  <h3 class="display-1">Forgot password</h3>
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

password_reset_confirm.html

```
{% extends 'reg_base.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% block body_block %}
  {% if validlink %}
    <h3 class="display-2 text-center">Change password</h3>
    <form class="form-control" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% bootstrap_form form %}
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Change password</button>
    </form>
  {% else %}
    <p class="lead">
      The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used.
      Please request a new password reset.
    </p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

---

installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap3',
    'accounts',
]
```

The main Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.HomepageView.as_view(),name='home'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include("accounts.urls")),
    url(r'^accounts/', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough info. Where are your templates located? What is your `TEMPLATES` setting? What is your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. How are you including those URLs?

Comment: please refer to the photo link provided in the question [EDITED]

Comment: He asked you to show the settings for the templates. I think the problem is that you did not specify Django where to look for templates and when he does not find them, he uses the standard ones. Also, in your main URLs file, delete the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `django.contrib.admin` above `accounts` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. That means that the `registration/password_reset_form.html` from `django.contrib.admin` will be found first and used instead of the template from `accounts`.

You can either move `accounts` above `django.contrib.admin` so that Django searches that app first, or rename the template name to something that doesn't clash (e.g. `registration/my_password_reset_form.html`) and update your URL pattern with the new template name.